# Siegel zeros are simple and real

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I've seen this fact mentioned often in the literature, but I've never seen a proof.

> Can someone suggest a reference where this is proved?

I haven't found it in the usual places (Iwaniec-Kowalski, Davenport...)

Answer (score 1):

On pages 91-92, Davenport considers the case of a complex zero β+iγ (and then also its conjugate.) The same reasoning can be applied to two real zeros (including a double zero), showing that if there is a Siegel zero, then it is necessarily real and simple. This fact is also contained in Theorem 11.3 (beginning on page 360) of Montgomery and Vaughan.